# How to set environment for Angular 7 in tfs build pipeline

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I am trying to set a specefic environment in tfs build pipeline but it always set dev environment which is the default. However, ng serve command works fine.

Here are my application version details.

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.16.0
@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.13.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.9
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.9
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.9
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      7.3.9
```

Here is how I have configured.

**environments >**

```
└── environments
        ├── environment.prod.ts
        ├── environment.staging.ts
        └── environment.ts
```

**angular.json**

```
"configurations": {
  "production": { ... },
  "staging": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
```

**angular.json > serve**

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "my-app:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "staging": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:staging"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:production"
            }
          }
```

**build pipeline scripts >**

[image]

I have tried running different commands but nothing helped.

```
build --prod --configuration=staging
build --prod --configuration staging
build --configuration=staging
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this setting in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "stag": "ng build --configuration=staging",
  },
```

Then just use `npm run stag` in pipeline

So your `npm command` option is `run stag`. No need for argument

Answer (score 0):

After setting your custome build command in package.json

```
"scripts": {
"staging": "ng build --configuration=staging",
```

},

when using in your local computer use `npm run staging` but when using in azure build use custome command and your command argument `run stagin`

[image]